# PHP | Powershell script outputting data

Tags: php, windows, powershell, formatting

I have a powershell script which searches the **active directory** for the given username and returns properties about that user, here is the script:

```
Param([string]$username)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser $username -Properties GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Enabled, PasswordExpired, Created, LastLogonDate
```

As you can see, I have given it a list of properties I want to be returned, and it returns it successfully. The problem is that it also returns other things which I **dont** want, such as the "DistinguishedName". Look below at what I am returned with:

```
Created           : 30/07/2014 11:55:39
DisplayName       : Testing Acount
DistinguishedName : CN=Testing Acount,OU=Disscuss,OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=Company,DC=local
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Testing
LastLogonDate     : 18/08/2014 12:27:40
Name              : Testing Acount
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : d135516b-4c10-41f1-9fa5-4f48bcacc891
PasswordExpired   : False
SamAccountName    : testingacount
SID               : S-1-5-21-1161181520-173477490-3285844792-2188
Surname           : Acount
UserPrincipalName : testingacount@company.local
```

How do I tackle a problem like this and make it ONLY return the properties I have stated, or perhaps even filtering through it after and removing the unwanted bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe your `Get-ADUser` command to a `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ADUser $username | Select-Object GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Enabled, PasswordExpired, Created, LastLogonDate
```

This should give you back only the elements you want.

Edit: The `Get-ADUser` command doesn't return all the properties you want. You need to use the `-Properties` parameter and then pipe it to a `Select-Object`

```
 Get-ADUser $username -Properties GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Enabled, PasswordExpired, Created, LastLogonDate | Select-Object GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, Enabled, PasswordExpired, Created, LastLogonDate
```

Here's the technet page for the `Get-ADUser` function: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx

Comment: This is not working very well for me. This is what im returned with: http://puu.sh/bctE1/aa8b609245.png as you can see, some are empty with no result. I changed it back to the old one and all properties had values.

Comment: It seems that the default set returned from `Get-ADUser` function doesnt return all the properties you want so you have to use the -Properties parameter and then pipe it to the Select-Object.